# Simple algorithm to get the square of an integer using only addition?

Tags: number-theory, arithmetic, square-numbers

This problem was mentioned in passing in a reading and it piqued my curiosity.

I'm not sure where to start. Any pointers? (perhaps square *root* was meant?)

Comment: You mean expressing $a^2$ as $a + a + a + \ldots + a$?

Comment: I imagine (hope) that wasn't what was meant.

Comment: There is "[exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring)" so presumably there is "multiplication by doubling"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An algorithm to do this for integers would be (in pseudo-code):

```
 input a
 b = abs a
 s = 0
 while b > 0 do
      s = s + a
      b = b - 1
 return s
```

Comment: It would be easier using a `for` loop.

Comment: In my opinion, a "**for** _var_ _startval_ _endval_ `operation`" loop is a higher level and less flexible construction than either a "**repeat** `operation` **until** `condition`" or a "**while** `condition` **do** `operation`"

Answer (score 3):

$(n+1)^2 = n^2 + n + n + 1 $

recursion rocks:

$f(0)=0,\,f(n+1)=f(n)+n+n+1,\,n\geq0$

Comment: It would be useful to be a bit more specific, though... How about $f(0) = 0, f(n+1) = f(n) + n + n + 1$?

Comment: @JohannesKloos done!
In my defense, the author asked for pointers, not solutions :)

Answer (score 1):

You can determine the square of any real number $n$ by adding the square of $(n-1)$, plus $n-1$, plus $n$. The formula is $n^2 = (n-1)^2 + (n-1) + n$ . E.g.

to find the square of $4$, add the square of $3$, plus $3$, plus $4$ or $9+3+4 = 16$
to find the square of $9$, add the square of $8$, plus $8$, plus $9$ or $64+8+9 = 81$

While you could code a nifty recursive function to determine the square of $n-1$, most systems limit levels of recursion so you will encounter an error when you reach the limit, thus limiting the starting number range. Better to use a loop.

Also, if you're nit-picking, this formula uses subtraction and the original problem mentioned using only addition. In that case, add $a-1$ to $n$ and you should be in conformation with the restriction to only use addition.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for formatting.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use the trivial solution $$n^2=n+n+n+\cdots+n=\sum_{k=1}^n k$$ use that $$n^2=1+3+5+\cdots+(2n-1)=\sum_{k=1}^n (2k-1)$$

Answer (score -1):

$$a^2= 2((a - 1) + (a - 2) + ... + 1) + a$$

Imagine a square of side 5 units
(Going clockwise) Add one side (5), then another (4) on and on...

It will give you this:
$$2\times(4 + 3 + 2 + 1) + 5 = 25 = 5^2$$